# Информация из БД в новой Activity (Android)

Tags: android, база-данных, activity, imagebutton

Здравствуйте, делаю приложение в котором имеется база данных с информацией по каждому университету. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ImageButton с логотипом вуза открывалось Activity(уже имеется) с информацией конкретно этого вуза из базы данных. Кнопку сделал, не знаю как воспользоваться бд.

Comment: воспользоваться поиском. примеров работы с бд очень много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы в активити получить данные из БД, выбор которых был сделан в другой активити в первую очередь нужно организовать БД. Сделать каждой записи уникальный идентификатор. В БД Android такой идентификатор должен присутствовать обязательно в любом случае, иметь имя колонки *_id* и параметр колонки `INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT` - такая колонка будет автоматически получать уникальные значения и ничего самому туда записывать не нужно. Организуем БД следующим образом:

```
_id | Title  |  Content
-----------------------
1   |  Инст1 | описание
2   |  Инст2 | описание
```

Теперь нам просто нужно передать в активити с подробной информацией тот ID, информацию записи которого надо вывести. Делаем это через `Intent`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
     long ID;
    {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                  // вывести запись с ID = 1 (в нашем случае будет Инст1)
                  ID = 1; 
                break;   
            case R.id.button2: 
                  ID = 2; // вывести запись с ID = 2
                break;   
        }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , InfoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

В активити подробной информации принимаем этот ID и делаем запрос в БД на выборку данных по ID (это нужно реализовать отдельно):

```
public class InfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

        long ID = getIntent.getLongExtra("ID");
        Cursor info = database.getFromID(ID); //данный метод реализуется в классе работы с БД и содержит запрос на данные в БД по их ID
    }
}
```

Если в вашей БД гарантированно не будут повторятся, например, названия институтов (столбец title в нашем случае), то выборку можно делать по ним.

Это простейшая схема. На практике рекомендую использовать библиотеку Room Persistent Library от Google и другие компоненты из [Archetecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) (Live Data, Room, View Model и тд)

Comment: `getFromID` -> `findById`?

Comment: @Flippy, да назвать можно как нравится и понятнее прогеру, это не настолько принципиально. По моему пониманию, это все же выборка данных по значению, а не поиск элемента :)